# How to add script to the bottom of all pages in sitecore site?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I need to add a script to the bottom of all the pages on a specific sitecore site, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I thought to go to the site level and considered adding it to the "Tracking Codes" field, but I'm not certain this is the right way to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it didn't matter where I placed the script. I put it in the copyright section of the footer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

We can add the script in all page in below two ways.

**1:** Add the script in Layout after bottom placeholder section.
Mostly footer is extreme bottom component which is placed.

**2:** Create component with RTE field and place the script in RTE field. And add this componant in bottom of the paye through standard value.